Is it necessary to call torch.no_grad() even in evaluation mode?
I am learning pytorch. In the code examples, the model is switched between training and testing by using the model.train() and model.eval() modes. I understand that this has to be done to deactivate training specific behaviour such as dropouts and normalisation and gradient computation while testing.
In many such examples, they also use torch.no_grad(), which I understand is a way of explicitly asking to stop the calculations of the gradients.
My question is, if gradient calculation is stopped in model.eval() mode then why do we also have to set torch.no_grad()?
Below is an example of a code where both model.eval() and torch.no_grad() is used
class QuertyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.input = nn.Linear(2, 8)
        
        self.hl1 = nn.Linear(8, 16)
        self.hl2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.hl3 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.hl4 = nn.Linear(16, 8)
        
        self.output = nn.Linear(8, 3)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hl1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hl2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hl3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hl4(x))
        
        return self.output(x)

Function to train the model
def train_model(model, lr, num_epochs):
    
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    train_acc, train_loss, test_acc, test_loss = [], [], [], []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f"{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")
        
        model.train() # switch to training mode
        
        batch_acc, batch_loss = [], []
        for X, y in train_loader:
            # forward pass
            y_hat = model(X)
            loss = loss_function(y_hat, y)
            
            # backward pass
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
            matches = torch.argmax(y_hat, axis=1) == y # true/false
            matches = matches.float() # 0/1
            
            batch_acc.append(100*torch.mean(matches))
            batch_loss.append(loss.item())
        
        train_acc.append(np.mean(batch_acc))
        train_loss.append(np.mean(batch_loss))
        
        model.eval() # switch to evaluation mode
        
        X, y = next(iter(test_loader))
        with torch.no_grad():
            y_hat = model(X)
        
        test_acc.append(100*(torch.mean(y_hat) == y).float())    
        test_loss.append(loss_function(y_hat, y).item())
        
    return train_acc, train_loss, test_acc, test_loss


.train() or .eval() only modify some behaviour of some layers of the network (like BatchNorm, Dropout, etc.), they do not explicitly allow or block the gradient of the model, so for inference, you should call torch.no_grad() to stop the intermediate values being stored

so if I am not mistaken, setting the model to eval mode does not stop the gradient calculations?

@Sashaank Nope. They will still calculate gradient if you call .backward().
